# Make ListviewActivity performance smooth android

Tags: android

I have a SearchListActivity which uses CustomSimpleCursor for adapter. In that CustomSimpleCursor I used many codes for the operations ,due to that the performance of SearchListActivity has come to a level bacause of which it hangs when scrolling

The SearchListActivity has

1. Three-Imageview of which ,One-animates on scrolling
2. 13 textview

Please help me , how to alter the SearchListActivity ,so that the performance increases

CustomSimpleCursor.java

```
public class CustomSimpleCursor extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    Typeface font;
    TextView txtDaysRemainigValue,txtTurnsAge;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomSimpleCursor(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);            

            String todayBD = null;
            //Zodiac icon
            try {
                    ImageView thumbZodiacIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                    InputStream bitmap = context.getResources().getAssets().open(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BirthdayProvider.ZODIAC_ICON)));
                    Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                    thumbZodiacIcon.setImageBitmap(bit);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }

         // Event icon 
            try {
                    ImageView thumbEventIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
                    InputStream bitmap = context.getResources().getAssets().open(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_ICON)));
                    Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                    thumbEventIcon.setImageBitmap(bit);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Contact photo
            try {
                ImageView thumbContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                byte bitmapData[]=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO));   
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.length);
                thumbContact.setImageBitmap(bit);               
                Animation localAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.fadein_image);
                thumbContact.startAnimation(localAnimation);

        } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Days remaining for BD  

         txtDaysRemainigValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);            
         String year=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_YEAR));
         String month=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_MONTH));  
         String date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DATE));
         String remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);

          Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
          int CMonth=(today.get(Calendar.MONDAY)+1);
          int CDate=(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


          txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));
          txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 27);

          //checking whether the BD is on TODAY

          if (remainingDays.equals("1") && (CDate==Integer.parseInt(date) && (CMonth)==Integer.parseInt(month))) {

              Log.v("else if executed","else if executed");
              Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom month"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+(CMonth)+"="+month);
             Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom date"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+CDate+"="+date);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00CC33"));
            remainingDays="today".toLowerCase();
        }

          //checking whether the BD is on TOMORROW
          else if (remainingDays.equals("1")) {

             Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom month"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+(CMonth)+"="+month);
             Log.v("Remainin Days",remainingDays+" = Custom date"+ cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.NAME))+"="+CDate+"="+date);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
            remainingDays="tomorrow".toLowerCase();
        }


        //checking how many days remaining BD
          else{
              remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 27);
              txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));

          }

          txtDaysRemainigValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_days_left);    
          font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "DS_DIGIB.ttf");
          txtDaysRemainigValue.setTypeface(font);            
          txtDaysRemainigValue.setText(remainingDays);

      //Turns age 
        txtTurnsAge=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);         
        String turnsAge=BirthdayCalculation.getAge(Integer.parseInt(year),Integer.parseInt(month),Integer.parseInt(date));
        txtTurnsAge.setText(turnsAge);


      //Event week
        try {

            TextView txtEventWeek=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_next_bd);       
            String eventWeek=BirthdayCalculation.getDayOfWeek(year, month, date);
            font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Comic Sans.ttf");
            txtEventWeek.setTypeface(font);
            txtEventWeek.setText(eventWeek);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 



        // Contact Name

        TextView txtNumber=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_contact_number);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtNumber.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtBirtgDay=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_birthdate);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtBirtgDay.setTypeface(font);


        TextView txtZodiac=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtZodiac.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtZodiacValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_zodiac);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Comic Sans.ttf");
        txtZodiacValue.setTypeface(font);


        TextView txtNextBD=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto_Light.ttf");
        txtNextBD.setTypeface(font);


        TextView txtTurnsAge=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image_arrow);  
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "athletic.ttf");
        txtTurnsAge.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtDayRemainig=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TextView04);    
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "athletic.ttf");
        txtDayRemainig.setTypeface(font);

        TextView txtTurnsAgeValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtview_turns);    
        font=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "DS_DIGIB.ttf");
        txtTurnsAgeValue.setTypeface(font);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso) library for lazy-loading the images in a background thread and caching them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you should do is to use TAG with static class and attributes, for example:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Car> cars;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Car car = getItem(i);
        CarViewHolder carViewHolder;
        if (view == null || view.getTag() == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_car, viewGroup, false);
            carViewHolder = new CarViewHolder();
            carViewHolder.mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view;
            carViewHolder.factoryTV = (TextView) carViewHolder.mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.factoryTV);
            carViewHolder.kmTV = (TextView) carViewHolder.mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.kmTV);
            carViewHolder.nameTV = (TextView) carViewHolder.mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            carViewHolder.yearTV = (TextView) carViewHolder.mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.yearTV);
        } else {
            carViewHolder = (CarViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        carViewHolder.factoryTV.setText(car.getFabricante());
        carViewHolder.kmTV.setText(NumberFormat.getInstance().format(car.getQuilometragem()).toString());
        carViewHolder.nameTV.setText(String.valueOf(car.getNome()));
        carViewHolder.yearTV.setText(String.valueOf(car.getAno()));

        view.setTag(carViewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Car getItem(int i) {
        return cars.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return cars.indexOf(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cars.size();
    }
}

static class CarViewHolder {
    LinearLayout mainLayout;
    TextView nameTV;
    TextView factoryTV;
    TextView yearTV;
    TextView kmTV;
}
```

For more information:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html